# Unable to install tm package on Windows

Tags: r, tm

I need help in installing tm package in RStudio 1.0.153 (R v.3.4.4) on Windows 10.

So, I've been wanting to install tm package in my rstudio. I have tried installing through devtools (using `devtools::install_cran("tm)` and installing the depdendecies one at a time (i.e. nlp and slam).

Yet, nothing beats the message below:

```
package ‘NLP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : cannot open file '\\xxx.xxx.xx/xxxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/file3314e435bf1/tm/texts/acq/reut-00001.xml': Invalid argument
```

*.The xxx is just a replacement for directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to install tm package

```
install.packages("tm")
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehul, guess I forgot to mention that I've tried that one as well.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot when you try to install tm package with install.packages("tm")

Comment: Hi @Mehul, I think the error message above is self-explanatory. Whichever command I run, it still gives me that error message. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I have just installed tm package and its working fine with Rstudio 1.1.442 and R version 3.4.4  Try to update your software and try it.